# How to get the code in R?

Tags: r

I am running the following code

```
 x=wilcox.test(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```

Now my question is: How to see the R code of this test? When I am running "wilcox.test" in console, it is printing

```
 function (x, ...) 
  UseMethod("wilcox.test")
 <bytecode: 0x3d73148>
 <environment: namespace:stats>
```

This question may be very trivial but I am stuck here.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I dont get that output, i just get,

x

 Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  rnorm(10) and rnorm(10)
W = 56, p-value = 0.6842
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess The output that you are describing can be obtained with `wilcox.test(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))`. But the OP is reporting on the output of `wilcox.test`, typed directly in the console, without passing arguments to the function and without parentheses at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
methods("wilcox.test")
```

to find out which methods are implemented. Then use `getAnywhere` to see the method you are interested in:

```
getAnywhere("wilcox.test.default")
```

Comment: Thank you....I got the answer.